# mend.findItem explanation and confusion

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and kinda to Java as well.
I'm learning how to add buttons to actionbar - everything is working, but I don't understand few things.

```
//Showing small icons at actionbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.recBin); // Finds the button in Actionbar and gets the ID
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.recBin: // Actions for delete button
            dbHandler.remove(getID());
            displayTaskList();
            menuItem.setVisible(false); // Hide the button
            break;
        case R.id.editBtn: // Actions for editbutton

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "EDIT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case R.id.closeBtn:  

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "CLOSE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This line: menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.**recBin**); Is for what exactly? I took it off and my app crashed, so I understand that it's mandatory. What I don't understand is what icons ID should I put at bold space? It has to be from "menu" right, but does it matter which id I take? For instance, if I took R.id.**closeBtn** instead of recBin? As long as it's an id from menu, it works? 
P.S. I hope this isn't a terrible question [probably is] and I'm sorry if so.

**Solution:**
Turns out you can simply get ID's. Stupid and simple.

```
private                 MenuItem                item1, item2, item3;

//Showing small icons at actionbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.recBin); // Rec button
    item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.editBtn); // Edit button
    item3 = menu.findItem(R.id.closeBtn); // Close button

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.recBin: // Actions for delete button
        dbHandler.remove(getID());
        displayTaskList();
        item1.setVisible(false); item2.setVisible(false); item3.setVisible(false);             // Hiding all buttons
        break;
    case R.id.editBtn: // Actions for editbutton

        item1.setVisible(false); item2.setVisible(false); item3.setVisible(false);             // Hiding all buttons
        break;
    case R.id.closeBtn:
        item1.setVisible(false); item2.setVisible(false); item3.setVisible(false);             // Hiding all buttons
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a reference to MenuItem, but it would be easier if you do:

```
case R.id.recBin: // Actions for delete button
        dbHandler.remove(getID());
        displayTaskList();
        item.setVisible(false); // Hide the button
        break;
```

You can safely remove the reference afterwards

Comment: Thanks. Found a solution - and the end of the topic.